# Spring Cloud Gateway - navigate to a second gateway app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

Hello what I am trying to achieve is the following:

I have 2 gateway apps
from gateway app 1, I want users to be redirected to gateway app 2 whenever they navigate to /sales/**

Current route I have in my yaml file:

```
        - id: rewrite-location-route
          uri: http://gateway2-app
          predicates:
            - Path=/sales/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=gateway1, gateway2
```

my idea is that if a user navigates to gateway1.extraUrlpart.com/sales/anything, they get redirected to gateway2.extraUrlpart.com/sales/anything

Comment: What is you question exactly?